# Conditional variables in a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to use a makefile to allow for different types of parallelism in my code. In the past I would just use completely different makefiles/versions of the code, but I'm trying to step up my game a little bit.

To start off, I would like to make a serial and OpenMP version. I want to use `-DUSEOMP` flag if I am building the OpenMP version, but am have trouble redefining the `DEFS` variable in that case. Here is my makefile right now:

```
# the c++ compiler we are using
CXX = g++ 
# the executable file to be created
EXE = disrecon.exe
# the c++ flags we use for compilation
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
# #defines to the program
DEFS = 

# the object files
OBJS = 

serial: $(OBJS) xdriver.cpp
  @echo "Making serial version"
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) xdriver.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEFS)

omp: $(OBJS) xdriver.cpp
  @echo "Making OpenMP version"
  DEFS += -DUSEOMP
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) xdriver.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEFS)


clean:
  rm -rf *.o
```

This should, by default, make the serial version but make the `omp` version if I specify `make omp`. Right now, I cannot redefine (or add to) to `DEFS` variable. I will need to do this for other included libraries, etc. later on, so how do I add to the list of variables in a specific section like this?

Comment: People usually use automake for more complex makefile stuff, look at this for example http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/true.html#true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried the shell variable approach, but a Make [target-specific](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) variable should be the best way to go.
You can add the following line

```
omp: DEFS += -DUSEOMP
```

to your Makefile, which should look like

```
# the c++ compiler we are using
CXX = g++ 
# the executable file to be created
EXE = disrecon.exe
# the c++ flags we use for compilation
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
# #defines to the program
DEFS = 

# the object files
OBJS = 

serial: $(OBJS) xdriver.cpp
  @echo "Making serial version"
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) xdriver.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEFS)

omp: DEFS += -DUSEOMP

omp: $(OBJS) xdriver.cpp
  @echo "Making OpenMP version"
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) xdriver.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEFS)


clean:
  rm -rf *.o
```